# How to add connection string for a windows form applicaton in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, database-connection

I am working on a windows form application and I want to add connection string of a database. Though I can access the database I don't know the proper reasoning behind it.
I have created a database and added it in a "Database" folder. The code for it is given below. I also want to know how can I make a connection string which can work on different PCs without changing it (I'm talking about relative path given in the "AttachDbFilename" attribute in the connection string).

```
Conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename="+ Application.StartupPath + "\\Database\\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
```

Comment: I suggest you to read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973824.aspx) since you are missing the idea behind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using :

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData(“DataDirectory”,”c:\anypath”);

SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection (“Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Initial Catalog=Master");
```

As documented here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring.aspx